# IndexOutOfBoundsException not working

Tags: java, bluej

i am trying to display an error message when the index is out of bounds but my current code is not displaying the appropriate error message even when there are no elements in the array list.

here is the block of code for the section i am trying to implement to exception to.
to explain, the make call method gets the display which is a number that corresponds with array elements then displays the call from the correct index.

```
public void makeCall()
{
    Mobile phoneCall = (Mobile) gadgets.get(getDisplay());
    phoneCall.PhoneCall(getPhoneNumber(), getDuration());
    System.out.println();
}

public int getDisplay()
{
    int gadgetDisplay = 0;
    try
    {
        gadgetDisplay = Integer.parseInt(displayText.getText());

    if (gadgetDisplay< 0)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
      (frame, "Please enter a positive Display");  
    }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException exception)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        (frame, "Please enter a positive Display");
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException exception)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        (frame, "Gadget is not listed");
    }
    return gadgetDisplay;
}
```

Comment: Where is the `ArrayList`, which is apparently **empty** on which you're trying to get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: the problem is that the second catch method does not display the error message. the array list is separate. i am just trying to get the exception to show an error message rather than crashing.

Comment: @user2290426: there's nothing in the code you've posted that would generate that exception. (Unless `displayText.getText()` does, but that would be a strange interface.)

Comment: @user2290426- Having the array list in some other place, and wanting to catch the exception pertaining to it in some other place, make NO SENSE whatsoever. The arraylist under scanner, must be present in this `TRY` for this `CATCH` to catch any exception related to it!

Comment: sorry,  should have explained the code better. its a GUI so the code i have shown is a text field. when the number is written in the field it will get the appropriate array list element. i have the number format exception but i dont know how to implement the out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if need to check the size then you can call the size() method, also you can throw the exception so makeCall method could decide the action:

```
public void makeCall() {
    try {
        Mobile phoneCall = (Mobile) gadgets.get(getDisplay());
        phoneCall.PhoneCall(getPhoneNumber(), getDuration());
        System.out.println();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException exception) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please enter a positive Display");
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Gadget is not listed");
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please enter a positive Display");
    }
}

public int getDisplay() throws NumberFormatException
{
    int gadgetDisplay = Integer.parseInt(displayText.getText());

    if (gadgetDisplay < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter a positive Display");  
    }
    else if ( gadgetDisplay >= yourList.size() ) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Gadget is not listed");
    }

    return gadgetDisplay;
}
```

or you can do it in one method:

```
public void makeCall() {
    try {
        int gadgetDisplay = Integer.parseInt(displayText.getText());

        if (gadgetDisplay < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please enter a positive Display");
        }
        else if ( gadgetDisplay >= yourList.size() ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Gadget is not listed");
        }
        else {
            Mobile phoneCall = (Mobile) gadgets.get(getDisplay());
            phoneCall.PhoneCall(getPhoneNumber(), getDuration());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException exception) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please enter a positive Display");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second catch block will only be executed if the code in your try block throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Currently there is nothing in your try block which will throw that exception. As you say the `ArrayList` is handled elsewhere, you will most likely need to put the code that is trying to access an element of the `ArrayList` inside its own try catch block. The exception needs to be handled there.

To be honest I think you have posted the wrong piece of code here.

Comment: thanks for the information. the array list is implemented somewhere else but you are correct that i have to access the elements inside the method for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your doesn't produce Desired exception since you are not trying to do something so exception will occur.

OutOfBound exception means you are trying to get a value from out of range

```
public int getDisplay()
{
    int gadgetDisplay = 0;
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
    arr.add("a");
    try
    {
        String str = arr.get(3);

    if (gadgetDisplay< 0)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
      (frame, "Please enter a positive Display");  
    }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException exception)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        (frame, "Please enter a positive Display");
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException exception)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        (frame, "Gadget is not listed");
    }
    return gadgetDisplay;
}
```

Above code will generate exception.
And i am not sure how you are expecting Exception from ArrayList

Comment: Are you sure? It'll throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and not `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Use an `ArrayList` there.

Comment: thanks. i had to access the array list inside the method for it to work. i have it functioning now.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a try / catch block to do this - you already know how many elements are in the ArrayList so just use [size()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size%28%29) to ensure that the number is in the range.